# Error "TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment" while assigning values from one Combo box to another using Python ,Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

in my Python UI using Tkiner there are  two Combo boxes , From one Combo box i am passing the values to another
Combo box based on the values from the first . The values are stored in the DB and retrieved from the DB .If the code runs from the begining the combo boxes displays the correct values . But if i append any new value to the list .In the Combo Box1 the values are appended and works fine but it gives an error at the second Combo box where i assign the values . The values are assigned as a list. Can any one plese tell what could be the issue . Attached below is the snippet

```
 def SelectTagPosition(self,event=None):
    self.positionID=event.widget.get()
    oConn = sqlite3.connect( 'VideoTags.db' )
    curs = oConn.cursor()

    # for displaying in the Select Regio Combo box
    curs.execute("select PolygonID from VideoPolygonTable where videoID = " + str( self.curVideoInfoID ) + " and position = " + str( self.positionID ) )
    self.polygonIds = curs.fetchall()
    print("Select Region",self.polygonIds)
    oConn.close()
    #self.SelectRegionComboBox.state="normal"
    self.SelectRegionComboBox['values']=self.polygonIds
    print("Select Region ,self.curVideoInfoID",self.curVideoInfoID)
    self.GetVideoPolygonsForPosition( self.curVideoInfoID, self.positionID )
    #self.totalVideoFrames=self.cap.get(7)
    self.cap.set( 1, int(self.positionID) )
    ret, frame = self.cap.read()
    self.VideoFrameSavedInDB=frame
    polygonLen = len( self.curVideoPolyons )
    if polygonLen > 0:
        self.DrawPolygonsOnSavedImagefromDB()

def SelectRegionPosition(self,event):
    self.regionId = event.widget.get()
    self.polygonIdToBeDeleted=self.regionId
    self.polygonIdToBeEdited=self.regionId
    self.DeletePolygonButton['state']='normal'
    self.EditPolygonButton['state'] ='normal'
    self.SaveEditsButton['state']='normal'
    oConn = sqlite3.connect( 'VideoTags.db' )
    curs = oConn.cursor()
    self.SelectRegionComboBox['values'] = self.polygonIds
    curs.execute("select * from VideoPolygonTable where PolygonID = " + str(self.regionId  ) + " and position = " + str( self.positionID ) )
    self.regionCoordinates = curs.fetchall()
    #self.curVideoPolygonData.append(self.regionData)
    self.DrawSelectedPolygonOnImage()
```

The two combo  boxes are set as below:

```
I have initialized it in a class called GUI :self.TagPositionComboBox = ttk.Combobox( TagsButtonPanel,textvariable=self.tagPositionComboBoxVar)
    self.TagPositionComboBox.set( "Tag Position" )
    self.TagPositionComboBox.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10,pady=20)
    self.TagPositionComboBox.bind( '<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.SelectTagPosition )
    #self.selectRegionComboBoxVar = tk.StringVar()
    self.SelectRegionComboBox = ttk.Combobox(TagsButtonPanel)#, textvariable=self.selectRegionComboBoxVar )
    self.SelectRegionComboBox.set( "Select Region" )
    self.SelectRegionComboBox.grid(row=0, column=5, padx=10, pady=20)
    self.SelectRegionComboBox.bind( '<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.SelectRegionPosition )
```

Comment: Post the full error with trace. It seems however like one of your `self.` elements is actually a string.

Comment: Hi the error is as below                                                                     
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:/GitLatest_today/tier3d_poc_engineering/windows/Tag_Video/TagVideoApp.py", line 467, in SelectTagPosition
    self.SelectRegionComboBox['values']=self.polygonIds
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Post it in the question and format it as code so it's legible. But ya, your `self.SelectRegionComboBox` is becoming a string at some point. You haven't posted the relevant code though for us to be able to tell where. It's likely happening near the code that calls these two functions.

Comment: I have initialized it in a class called GUI :

Comment: If the first function call isn't causing the same error, it's unlikely to be because of initialization. It's probably happening between the calls to `SelectTagPosition` and `SelectRegionPosition`. As a side note too, all those names should be lowercase. Capital letters are reserved for specific purposes, and breaking convention makes your code harder to read.

Comment: Search your code for `SelectRegionComboBox=`, ignoring the first initialization.